# Fireworks slices creates streaks in browser

Tags: png, adobe-fireworks, slices

this is what it looks like when ran in browser

[image]

behind the scene in Adobe Fireworks

[image]

Comment: Are you exporting the html from fireworks, I assume? This is not really what the slice tool is meant to do- can you explain a bit what you're trying to achieve with those image slices?

Comment: yes i exported it as HTML and images to embed it on my website. 

I am creating an Interactive 2D map of a subdivision where the user can view what lots are available and unavailable

Answer (score 2):

ok, the problem lies in the generated html. I cannot diagnose exactly, but I suspect it has generated a big table with nested tables with all this OR lots of relatively positioned divs. posting the html will help troubleshoot, but you can start by placing this on your html between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
<style>
  img{display:block;}
</style>
```

That might help get rid of the spaces around images.

A better way to achieve what you want is by using an [image map](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d35d-7fe6.html) with one big image with linked "hotspots" on it.